# Apps not being pushed to new device

Tags: google-play-store

Just got a new device, the Pixel. Had Samsung Galaxy before with a bunch of apps. That, in turn, was an upgrade from HTC. When I got it, all the previously installed apps were pushed to the Galaxy. I was expecting the same to happen with the Pixel, but nothing was pushed to it. The device is logged into the correct account and shows up as a registered device in the Play Store on the web. I can manually push apps to it and they install. But I have hundreds of them and was expecting them to install automatically. Why did they not? Is there a way to force it?

Comment: Did you have your Samsung set to backup to your Google account?

Comment: You can see what apps are backed up at https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard and open Android section

Comment: All apps got installed during the "restore" in the initial setup. However, most data for those apps did not. I was thinking this might be a feature of the apps that they don't backup their databases to the server. But looking at the dashboard you pointed out, I see the old phone has a whole lot more apps backed up than the new one. Am I possibly missing something?

Comment: Actually, only some apps are compatible with the Google App data backup system... I find more that are not than ones that are. You can see which ones have app data (typically only the app settings, not the actual data) backed up by going to link I posted previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on when you purchased your previous devices, you restored the devices during the initial setup window.

When booting up an Android device after a factory reset, you're greeted with the `Setup` app.

During this process, you add your Google account. In most cases, there is a link to restore your device, which will install apps associated with the google account to your device.

If you have yet to apply large amounts of data to the device, factory reset it so you go through the initial setup again, and look for a restore option.

If this doesn't show, no previous installations can be found, and you'll have to install apps manually.

Comment: This worked. I must have not selected "restore" during the initial setup, so I wiped to factory and made sure to select it this time. All apps got pushed.